# Invalid fingerprint for generating Google Map key for android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview

I have successfully generated the fingerprint Certificate for google map key by using these command

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\pc\.android
\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

and i got this result

```
androiddebugkey, Aug 25, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 68:1F:B8:80:C0:B9:96:D1:6E:95:86:69:CD:DB:0E:28:DC:9E:89:51
```

when i try to register Certificate fingerprint on this site https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

page replied me **The fingerprint you entered is not valid. Please press the Back button on your browser and enter a valid certificate fingerprint**

where is problem please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the solution of my problem just changed the command by this

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 2):

If your having issues finding the debug key path or dont want to use the adb you can get the fingerprint in eclipse:

go to window-->preferences and find the android section. Select the build sub-setting.

[image]

for the production fingerprint when your exporting your signed application using ADT right before you click finish the hash will be there. just copy it.